# Transforming list into dictionary with Python

Tags: python-3.x, transformation

There is a list of values:

```
list_inside = ["de:14612:1","de:14612:21","de:14612:17","de:14612:16"]
```

Why instead of `{'from': '1', 'to': '16'}` I am getting this `{'from': '16', 'to': '16'}`. What I am doing wrong with my code?

```
keys = ["from", "to"]

list_inside = ["de:14612:1","de:14612:21","de:14612:17","de:14612:16"]

for i in list_inside[::len(list_inside)-1]:
    result = dict((key, i.join(i.split(":", 2)[2::1])) for key in keys)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
keys = ["from", "to"]

list_inside = ["de:14612:1","de:14612:21","de:14612:17","de:14612:16"]
result = {}    #Declare empty dict
for key, v in zip(keys, list_inside[::len(list_inside)-1]):  
    result.update({key: v.split(":", 2)[-1])})  #Use dict.update to update the required values. 

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'to': '16', 'from': '1'}
```

Your current approach is overriding `result` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your doing `result =` several times inside a loop.

Obviously, only the last iteration will be effective here.

Answer (score 1):

This code gets the result what you are expecting.
`-1` made simple code.

```
keys = ["from", "to"]

list_inside = ["de:14612:1","de:14612:21","de:14612:17","de:14612:16"]

result = {}
result[keys[0]] = list_inside[0].split(':')[2]
result[keys[1]] = list_inside[-1].split(':')[2]

print (result)
```